# Converting decimal percentage to int

Tags: c#, int, double

I have a method that should convert a decimal percentage to and int
for example 0,73 should return 73.
I did the mess you see below but was wondering about a "nicer" solution.

```
 private static int ToPercentage(double d)
        {
            string temp = d.ToString("p");
            string temp2 = temp.Replace("%", "");
            double temp3 = Convert.ToDouble(temp2);
            int result = (int) temp3;
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: return (int)(d*100);

Comment: When converting a numeric value to another kind of numeric value, *why* would you do the intermediate steps of formatting it into a string and back?

Comment: This is like the opposite of Code Golf.

Comment: if it was 0.737 what should return? 73 or 74?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel bad writing this answer, but hopefully this will prevent all other answers and close the ticket.

```
private static int ToPercentage(double d)
{
    return (int)(d*100);
}
```

EDIT: Thanks Devid for the suggestion :) TIL how to make an answer a community wiki post!

Comment: If you feel so bad, then make your post a community wiki so nobody gets the points.

Comment: @DavidG, didn't know you can do that :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet of code. You don't need to convert to a string and then perform a replace.

```
private static int ToPercentage(double d)
    {
       int result = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(d * 100));
       return result;
    }
```